# SQL Server - PIVOT Grouping and Order By

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

quick question, I need to know how can I insert EmployeeID inside the `SELECT DISTINCT`.  When I try to insert like this:

```
STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(lt.[Description], lc.EmployeeID)
```

It gives me an error:

> Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
>   ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

This is the whole code:

```
DECLARE @LoanTypeDesc AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @LoanTypeDesc = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(lt.[Description]) 
                FROM LoanType lt INNER JOIN LoanContract lc ON lc.LoanTypeID = lt.LoanTypeID
                ORDER BY lc.EmployeeID
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
```

What I am trying to achieve is I am using a `PIVOT` to get the result of description and set it to columns.

Here is my pivot code:

```
SET @strQuery = 'SELECT *
FROM (
SELECT TOP 1000 EmployeeID,
    LoanAmount,
    lt.LoanTypeID,
    lt.[Description]
FROM LoanContract lc
INNER JOIN LoanType lt ON lt.LoanTypeID = lc.LoanTypeID
ORDER BY EmployeeID ASC
) src
PIVOT(
SUM(LoanAmount)
FOR Description IN (' + @LoanTypeDesc + ')
) piv;'
EXECUTE (@strQuery)
```

[image]

And I want to achieve something like this:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `lt.LoanTypeID` from select in pivot statement. This is because in pivot statement there are three parts: grouping, aggregation and spreading. In your case aggregation is `LoanAmount`, spreading is `lt.[Description]` and  **grouping column(s) are detected by elimination**. Simply speaking the rest columns. So result is being grouped by `EmployeeID` and `LoanTypeID`. As a general rule you will probably want to select 3 columns most of the time for pivot statement.

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day!

Comment: Thanks great explaination.